# How to prove $P(C−(A\cap B)) = P(C) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$ algebraically?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been trying for a while now. I can see how this works using venn diagrams but I'm having trouble proving it algebraically without going in circles. I start out using the Set Difference Law, but the resulting complements complicate everything.

Comment: Even though your notation might be self-explanatory, it is good practice to explain it, so that it is absolutely clear what you are asking about. So what do you mean by $P$, $A$, $B$ and $C$? Also, you might consider adding what properties you already know about probability. For example, say $X \subseteq Y$, then do you know that $P(Y - X) = P(Y) - P(X)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two sets $E$ and $F$, $E - F = E - (E \cap F)$.

Then, if $E=C$ and $ F = A \cap B$,

$$ P(C-(A \cap B)) = P(C - (A\cap B \cap C))$$

Because $A \cap B \cap C \subseteq C$,

$$ P(C - (A\cap B \cap C)) = P(C) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Comment: I think you mean $C \supseteq A \cap B \cap C$

Comment: @BDN Oops. Thank you for the correction.